# Where is the Ubuntu hardware compatibility list for individual parts?

Tags: hardware, compatibility

Where is the Ubuntu hardware compatibility list for individual parts? That is, where can peruse a list to build my own machine or evaluate one that is not an Ubuntu partner. I've looked around and found most lists abandoned, out-of-date, or the domain is for sale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/

You can find a list by components.

Comment: Good one! ;) (and an upvote!)

Comment: Note, though, that this is the list of officially certified hardware. A bunch of components that work may not be on the list because they never got official certification.

Comment: Wow, that list needs some work!  Empty box by unknown is certified! That's good to know!  No printer category though.